# Magento admin sidebar

Tags: magento, admin, sidebar

Does anyone know how to make a sidebar in the backend of Magento?

I'm talking about the navigation at the side as seen when editing a product. Google fails me when searching for "Magento admin sidebar", "Magento admin left navigation", "Magento admin left column", etc...

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow are expected to generally relate to programming or software development in some way, within the scope defined in the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: Making sidebars, widgets, grids, etc... appear in Magento involves coding html, php and xml... This was in no way a design question.

Anyway, I found this example which is exactly what I need:
http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/coffeefreak-blank-magento-extension-for-building-main-admin-menu-with-sidebar-and-tabs/

Comment: sure , I edited your question , but next time read the faq before you ask as this is a programming QA not discussion forum